# Java/Rust logging bridge

Tags: java, logging, rust

I have a Java program that uses JNI to call a Rust library.  In the rust code, I have calls to `info!` which do not appear in the output.  I am 99% positive this is because I am not initializing the Rust logging system.

When I had a similar problem in Python code calling Rust code, there was a module that I added which did the work to connect the Rust logging system to the python logger.

Is there a similar bridge for Rust and Java?

I am using `slf4j` in Java and `log::info` in Rust.

I searched for an bridge but the closest I found was how to call Rust from Java.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create your own logger (don't use env_logger or others):

```rust
use std::sync::Arc;
use log::{LevelFilter, Level};
pub type LogCallbackType = Arc<dyn Fn(Level, String) + Send + Sync>;
pub struct SimpleLogger {
  callback: LogCallbackType,
  level: LevelFilter,
}
```

2. Provide a function to bind a callback to your logger

```rust
impl SimpleLogger {
  pub fn init(level: LevelFilter, callback: LogCallbackType) {
    let message = std::format!("Initialize logging to {}", &level);
    callback(Level::Debug, message);

    log::set_boxed_logger(Box::new(SimpleLogger { callback, level }))
      .map(|()| log::set_max_level(level));
  }
```

3. Externalize your function to other languages

```rust
use std::os::raw::c_char;
pub type NativeString = *const c_char;
pub type ExternLogCallbackType = Option<extern "C" fn(u32, NativeString)>;

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn init_logging(level: u32, callback: ExternLogCallbackType) {
  if !callback.is_none() {
    let callback = callback.unwrap();
    let level_filter = SimpleLogger::u32_to_level_filter(level);
    SimpleLogger::init(level_filter, Arc::new(move |level, msg| {
      callback(level as u32, msg.as_ptr());
    }))
  }
}
```

4. Prepare the JNA stuff

```java
public static class LogCallback implements Callback {
  public static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger("myrustliblog");

  public void callback(int level, String message) {
    switch (level) {
      case 0:
        break;
      case 1:
        LOGGER.error(message);
        break;
      case 2:
        LOGGER.warn(message);
        break;
      case 3:
        LOGGER.info(message);
        break;
      case 4:
        LOGGER.debug(message);
        break;
      case 5:
        LOGGER.trace(message);
        break;
      default:
        LOGGER.trace(message);
        break;
    }
  }
}

public interface MyNativeInterface extends Library {
   //...other stuff ...

   String init_logging(int level, LogCallback callback);
   //...
}
```

5. Finally Initialize logging from Java:

```java
static final LogCallback LOG_CALLBACK = new LogCallback();

public static void initLogging(org.slf4j.event.Level level) {
    int iLevel = 0;
    switch (level) {
      case ERROR:
        iLevel = 1;
        break;
      case WARN:
        iLevel = 2;
        break;
      case INFO:
        iLevel = 3;
        break;
      case DEBUG:
        iLevel = 4;
        break;
      case TRACE:
        iLevel = 5;
        break;
    }
    _myInterfaceJnaInstance.init_logging(iLevel, LOG_CALLBACK);
  }
```

Notes:

1. I omitted result handling in Rust. You should be able to do it
2. This is from my running code, it works. But you might need to do a few tweaks for memory leaks (i.e. deallocate the strings after being logged).

Answer (score 0):

The `log` library provides only a mechanism for passing log messages to a global hook. Something must call [`log::set_logger()`](https://docs.rs/log/latest/log/fn.set_logger.html) with a function that does something with the messages. There are [a variety of libraries you can use for this purpose](https://docs.rs/log/latest/log/#available-logging-implementations); if you want to hook up your `log` logging to `slf4j` you will need to find or write code that does that combination specifically. (I don't know much of anything about JNI+Rust so I can't say whether one exists already.)